# How do I rearrange text in notepad++ for example how do I go from: “A”:”B” to “B”:”A” but for multiple unique lines?

Tags: notepad++

So basically I am trying to invert my text at a large scale, 70,000 lines using notepad++

I’m trying to get from this:

“A”:”B”

to this:

“B”:”A”

However, not all lines contain the same amount of characters.  Really I just want to invert everything from the left of the colon to the right, and everything from the right to the left of the colon.  How would I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+?):(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2:$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (.+?)       # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
    :           # a colon
    (.+)        # group 2, 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2      # content of group 2
:       # colon
$1      # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via Macros in Notepad++. Macros is basically a way to automate tasks by recording your keystrokes for one line then playing the recorded Macro for the whole document. Taking your example above, let's say we want to take

```
“A”:”B”
```

and turn it into this:

```
“B”:”A”
```

Here's what a step-by-step Macro would look like:

```
1. Verify your cursor is at the beginning of the document.
2. Start recording your Macro (Macro -> Start Recording).
3. Ctrl-f the colon (:).
4. Press the backspace key to delete the colon character. We will re-add that colon back in later.
5. Click and hold the Shift button, then press the home button. This will select all the characters to the left side of the colon.
6. Press Ctrl-x to cut the selection
7. Press the end button to take you to the end of the current line.
8. Type in your colon once again
9. Press Ctrl-v to paste your selection.
10. Stop recording your Macro.
11. Replay your Macro until the document's end.
```

This will effectively delete the colon, take every character before the colon and cut it, then add the colon again at the end of the line and add the cut out characters after the colon, effectively switching the position of the characters.

There are other ways of doing this using regex or other methods but this is the first that came to mind.

To learn more about Macros: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/macros/